# Which to prefer, Reykjavík Cars or Reykjavik Rent-a-car?

Tags: car-rentals, iceland, reykjavik

After reading a few fora, I decided to rent a car from "Reykjavík Cars" but then I realized that there are two separate companies with a similar name.

Is there a preference between these two / is one better than the other?

Comment: What's your basis for comparison, price, service, fleet  ?

Comment: My only concern is that I don't want to be taken for a ride in a new country. Prices are least priority for me. Honest service and reliable cars are utmost importance for us.

Comment: What does `better` mean?

Comment: Jo, good question. Better = Some one who is reliably more honest upfront and has good vehicles.